# C++ Should common data fields in derived classes be declared in base class?

Tags: c++

For a tic tac toe game I have a base class `Player` and two derived classes `HumanPlayer` and `AIPlayer`.

Both derived classes contain a data field `char token`. Should this field be included in the base class, so it wouldn't need to be declared in the derived classes?

Right now I am not explicitly declaring a constructor for `Player`, but would I need to if the data field `char token` was part of `Player`?

```
#pragma once // include guard
#include "Board.h"

class Player
{
    public:
        virtual void makeAMove(Board &myBoard) = 0; // pure virtual function
};
```

Header files of the derived classes:

```
#pragma once // include guard
#include "Player.h"

class HumanPlayer: public Player
{
    public:
        HumanPlayer(char token);
        virtual void makeAMove(Board &myBoard); 

    private:
        char token;
        int askForRow();    
        int askForColumn();
};

#pragma once // include guard
#include "Player.h"

class AIPlayer: public Player
{
    public:
        AIPlayer(char token);
        virtual void makeAMove(Board &myBoard);

    private:
        char token;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would make it a `protected` member of your `Player` base class and provide a constructor (used by the derived classes) that initializes it.

Also, you might instead make it `private` in your base class if your derived classes can access/use it via member functions that you add to the base class, but I think in the case of your game, it's probably fine to make it `protected`.

Comment: So, the derived classes wouldn't need constructors?

Comment: @navig8tr Yes, the derived classes do still need constructors.  But they could be of the form:  `explicit AIPlayer(char token) : Player(token) { }`

Comment: Okay, good that's what I just wrote in my code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Here's another crazy approach, assuming that the token is a *class* property and not an *instance* property: Make the token a template parameter:

```
template <char Token> class TokenPlayer : public Player
{
    static char const token = Token;
};

class HumanPlayer : public TokenPlayer<'H'>
{
    // ...
};
```

Within each `TokenPlayer` you can refer to the token by `Token`, and within each derived class by `token`.

Not sure if this makes sense for you, but it's another option, and it saves storage.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what generally works pretty well for me in these situations:

```
class Player
{
    public:
        ...

        char Token() const { return _token; }

    protected:
        void SetToken(char tok) { _token = tok; }

    private:
        char _token;
};
```

As usual, employing setter/getter hides the implementation allowing you to later replace the member `_token` with a computation, or make other changes without the client code having to worry about it.  Everybody can see the value, but only functions that 'should' be able to change it (derived classes of `Player`) are allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to put `token` into the base class. In that case you should provide a constructor for the base class and use it in the constructor of the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

For a tic tac toe game I don't see the need to create separate classes for your `Player` and `AI` logic. Both will be making decisions sure, but in the end, they both will essentially do the same thing: make a mark on the board. You will need special logic for the AI, but that can easily be abstracted away in another class. Your interface will be mainly catering to the `Player` input whether it is console input or a windows form for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to declare `token` etc. for every class that derives from `Player`, then yes. You should either make it a protected member of the base class, or provide `getToken()` and `setToken()` methods and make token a private member. You could of course make it a public member, but that's poor encapsulation.

And you don't strictly have to initialise its class members in a constructor either, but it's good practice to do so.